# unexpected alignment when use subfig package

Tags: captions, align, subfloats

When I use the code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,preprintnumbers]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{graph1}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{graph2}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch shell. A sea abundant with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship courses.}
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

The caption in the figure aligned like this

[image]

But when I add `\usepackage{subfig}` in the top, the caption in figure aligned like this

[image]

It seems that the caption is centering, but I want the caption justified on both sides, I try to put this code in the top

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
```

but it is useless, I want to ask how to make the caption justified on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `subfig` package as:

```
 \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

With this you preserve settings for captions in `revtex4`. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,preprintnumbers]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{graph1}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{graph2}
\caption{White sand beaches. The pink smoothness of the conch shell. A sea abundant with possibilities. Duty-free shops filled with Europe’s finest gifts and perfumes. Play your favorite game of golf amidst the tropical greens on one of the many championship courses.}
    \label{Fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]